# Using output of NSolve

Tags: plotting

I have a complicated function f(x,y)=0. It cannot be expressed in the form y=F(x). Now, I want to make a plot with (x, NSolve[f(x,y)==0],g(x,y)) from x=0 to 10, g(x,y) is another function of x,y and this will be the z coordinate.

For example, f(x,y)=x^2+y^2. (This is not a good example, since it can be expressed as y=x^2. The real case is much more complicated than this one. And note that there are two solutions y for x.)

Now I tried this to create a table of (x,y):

```
Table[{x, y/.NSolve[x^2+y==0,y]},{x,0,10,1}]
```

And the output is {{0,{0}}, {1,{-1}}, {2,{-4}},...}

There is a {} in the y value. And I cannot make a plot with this. How to solve this problem. And how to make a plot with (x,y,z=g(x,y)), for example g(x,y)=x+y. (I will use Plot3D, and it is a line in 3D space.)

Comment: for the 1st part of your question, maybe try `ContourPlot[ f(x,y)==0, {x,xmin,xmax},{y,ymin,ymax} ]`? I needed to solve a complicated equation recently and ContourPlot worked for me.

Comment: @Physicist I think you meant to type `f[x, y] == 0`.  `f(x, y)` would give a syntax error. -- This is mainly an FYI for newbies who read your comment. :)

Answer (score 2):

Let's take

```
g[x_, y_] := x + y
```

Then

```
pts = Flatten /@ Table[Block[{y1 = y1},
    {x, y1 = y /. NSolve[x^2 + y == 0, y], g[x, y1]}
    ] , {x, 0, 10}]
```

> {{0, 0., 0.}, {1, -1., 
>     0.}, {2, -4., -2.}, {3, -9., -6.}, {4, -16., -12.}, {5, -25.,
>   -20.}, {6, -36., -30.}, {7, -49., -42.}, {8, -64., -56.}, {9, -81.,
>   -72.}, {10, -100., -90.}}

```
ListPointPlot3D[pts, PlotStyle -> {PointSize[Large], Black}]
```

[image]

or joining the points:

```
ListPointPlot3D[pts, PlotStyle -> {PointSize[Large], Black}] /. Point -> Line
```

[image]

---

If `NSolve` gives two or more values of $y$, like `NSolve[y^2 - x == 0, y]` would do:

```
pts = Table[
  Block[{y1 = y1}, {x, y1 = y /. NSolve[y^2 - x == 0, y], 
    g[x, y1]}], {x, 3, 5}]
```

> {{3, {-1.73205, 1.73205}, {1.26795, 4.73205}}, {4, {-2., 2.}, {2., 6.}}, {5, {-2.23607, 2.23607}, {2.76393, 7.23607}}}

then to make a list of straightforward 3D points:

```
pts2a = Flatten[#, 1] &@
  Table[{pts[[All, 1]][[i]], ##} & @@@ (Transpose /@ 
       pts[[All, 2 ;;]])[[i]], {i, 1, Length@pts}]
```

or in a more transparent way:

```
pts2b = Flatten[
  Table[{pts[[i, 1]], pts[[i, 2, j]], pts[[i, 3, j]]}, {j, 1, 
    Length@pts[[i, 2]]}, {i, 1, Length@pts}], 1]
```

Both (up to the order) are the same:

```
Sort@pts2a == Sort@pts2b
```

> True

In this case joining the points isn't as unambiguous:

[image]

In general, joining the points depends on their order.

Comment: Thank you. It's very good. When I use this into my real problem, there is one problem needed to be fixed. What if there are two y solutions for one x value? For example, if f(x,y)=x^2+y^2-1 and {x,-1,1}. Another small problem, how to make a line plot instead of point plot in this case?  @corey979

Comment: E.g. when `NSolve[y^2 - x == 0, y]`, then `pts2 = Flatten[Table[
   {pts[[i, 1]], pts[[i, 2, j]], pts[[i, 3, j]]}
   , {j, 1, Length@pts[[i, 2]]}, {i, 1, Length@pts}]
  , 1]` - a dirty way made under the assumption that for every number of $y$'s found you'll compute the same number of $z$'s. This is a very dirty solution and surely there's a different, cleaner approach.

Comment: @QiZhong. Do not extend your question in a comment made to a answer. Update your question by editing it. As someone who has asked 14 questions on this site, you should now understand this site well enough to follow our protocols.

Answer (score 1):

Apply the solution list from `NSolve` to the form you want to generate each datum in the data.  Then `Join` the data from each solution set. For instance if you want to plot `{x, y, x^2 + y^2}` for each solution to `x^2 - 4 y + y^3 == 1` over a certain range of `x`, do the following:

```
Join @@ Table[
   {x, y, x^2 + y^2} /. NSolve[x^2 - 4 y + y^3 == 1, y, Reals],
   {x, 0, 10, 1}] // ListPointPlot3D
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Note: One can also use `Flatten[Table[..], 1]` instead of `Apply`-ing (`@@`) `Join` -- list manipulation problems generally have many solutions in *Mathematica*.